# Do all ESLint parsers handle the same options?

Tags: eslint

Do all ESLint parsers handle the same options?

My confusion arises from the fact that in the ESLint docs, there's a [section](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options) describing `parserOptions` indpenedent of [another section](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser) describing parser selection through the `parser` setting.

I've also checked out [@typescript-eslint/parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/parser) and its parser options, although the wording they use,

> The following **additional** configuration options are available by specifying them in parserOptions in your ESLint configuration file.

(emphasis mine)

does not make it clear whether they support all the options described in the `parserOptions` [section](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options) and therefore does not help me in determining whether all parsers should support the same base options.

Answer (score 0):

Short:definitely not.

The parseOptions is for parser, and it is not necessary to be the same, and sometimes not possible.